# free javascript widget to show an organigram chart

Tags: javascript, graphics, widget, treenode

I'm looking for a javascript widget to show some fairly complex graphes...

Ideally, it would be interactive, that is the user should be able to move around the nodes, select one or many, zoom in, click on a node to see more info, etc...

If it could have printing support, that would be marvelous...

The idea is to let the user browse the organization structure, and select one or more departments to create reports...

what I've found so far is the following

http://ondras.zarovi.cz/sql/demo/?keyword=default
(wow!!!)

(it uses http://code.google.com/p/oz-js/ just unzip the file and it works!)

http://thejit.org/
http://thejit.org/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html

http://javascript.neyric.com/wireit/
(very impresive!)
http://javascript.neyric.com/wireit/examples/jsBox/jsBox.html

do you know any other???

Answer (score 4):

This thing might be used for an organigram although it's originally intended for sitemaps:
[slickmap](http://astuteo.com/slickmap/)

Comment: right!!!! that's something pretty useful and simple, no js, no flash, no nothing, just plain html...

Answer (score 4):

A few years layer... [jQuery OrgChart](https://github.com/wesnolte/jOrgChart) is a plugin that allows you to render structures with nested elements in a easy-to-read tree structure. See a [demo](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4151695/html/jOrgChart/example/example.html) here.